# Facebook in-app browser not sharing location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, browser

i have a mobile friendly website which makes use of browser location to give nearby places of interest. Its working fine in all browser but when i try to load it from `facebook app` (Facebook app makes use of its own in app browser to open links ) it waits infinitely to take locations even though my phone's location in shared.

Can any one help in

1. How to get location from facebook in app browser.

   or
2. How to by pass fb in app browser to open my link in a browser.

Thanks

Comment: i am worried because now a days more people use `facebook app`  more in mobile than in `mobile browser` .

Comment: 2. It is not possible

Comment: @WizKid ok how to get location in that